# Not Able to get the 'Grade to Pass' from moodle quiz

Tags: php, sql, moodle

I need to get the 'grade to pass'  from each quiz to see if the student pass/fail based on the 'grade to pass' value provided by the teacher
[image]

I have tried something like below but the response is an empty array.Thanks in advance for the help.

```
$gradeitems=$DB->get_records('grade_items', array('id' => $quiz_id,'courseid' => $course_id));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'id' field in grade_items, is the id of the grade record itself, not the id of the activity associated with the grade.

If you want the grade associated with the quiz, then you need to look for one where 'itemmodule' is 'quiz' and 'iteminstance' is the id of the quiz (also good to check the 'courseid' as well, as there is a database index on that).

i.e.

```
$gradeitem = $DB->get_record('grade_items', ['itemmodule' => 'quiz', 'iteminstance' => $quizid, 'courseid' => $courseid]);
```

Comment: ```Array
(
    [50] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 50
            [courseid] => 8
            [categoryid] => 8
            [itemname] => Student Admissions Exam A
            [itemtype] => mod```   Can you please tell me what is 50 here(not the id)?

Comment: 50 is the id field of the record in the table mdl_grade_items.

Comment: echo $gradeitems[50] ->gradepass; I need to pass 50 here to get the gradepass.Do you know what to pass here instead of 50? How do I get that id beforehand?

Comment: Use $DB->get_record(), not get_records(), to only return a single result, or use reset() to get the first item in the array, or loop through each item in the array with foreach() or turn it into a 0-based array with array_values()

Comment: I am trying to get grade for each quiz attempt. Does grade_grades table contain the data required?what are the required fields to get the data?

Comment: grade_items has the grade definitions (max, min, pass, etc), grade_grades has the students' grades, with itemid being the id of the grade_items record

Comment: $gradegrades=$DB->get_record('grade_grades',array('itemid' => $item_id,'userid' => $user_id));  Worked. Thanks for the help.